# Count for specific column how much it has distinct values in different column

Tags: sql

I have columns app_id,http_host composed of the below rows: a-aa, a-bb, a-cc, b-hh. I want to calculate how much distinct values i have in column app_id for each distinct http_host. I want to get a-3, b-1

```
select app_id, http_host,
ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by app_id order by app_id desc) as rowNum 
FROM "public"."bus_request" 
group by app_id, http_host
```

I was thinking it will partition by app_id, it will have 1 for a and 2 for b but this is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

use distinct count

```
select app_id, count(distinct http_host)
from tablename
group by app_id
```

Answer (score 0):

use distinct count

```
select http_host,count(distinct app_id)
FROM "public"."bus_request" 
group by  http_host
```